# Python request send post request with params not as dictionary

Tags: python, http, post, request

So this seems like it would be a simple thing to do but I can't seem to get it to work. I want to send a post request to a local flask server running on my computer. So I use the following line of code to do it

```
r = requests.post(end_url + '/upload/flash', cookies=cookie, params='title=asdfg&description=asdfg&front1=f&back1=b&number=1&edu_level=&school=&course=&grade=&unit=&chapter=&section=&tag=')
```

The problem is not with the params I'm passing into the function as they are formatted correctly. The problem is that the flask server is trying to access the "title" arg from the request but can't find it. All of the examples I have seen format the params in a dictionary (ex.

```
{"title": "asdfg"}
```

I would imagine that it is possible to send a request the way I am trying but am not sure what I have done wrong.

Comment: You *must* send the params as a dict. Not sure why you're trying to use a string.

Comment: If you want your query-string parameters to be, well, a string, rather than a dict, then why not make them part of the URL? Like `/upload/flash?title=asdf&...`

Comment: @PaulM. Thank you for the response. I assume I would do that like this `r = requests.post(end_url + '/upload/flash?' + 'title=asdfg&description=asdfg&front1=f&back1=b&number=1&edu_level=&school=&course=&grade=&unit=&chapter=&section=&tag=', cookies=cookie)` If so I am still encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually not with the params. I was mixing up "params" and "data". I also needed to include the headers

```
headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
```

Thanks to everyone who help me troubleshoot my code.